# How to convert color image bitmap to black&white image bitmap in android?

Tags: android, bitmap

In my Business Card Reader android application, I need to convert **color image bitmap to black & white image bitmap (not gray scale image)** for OCR text reading. so please help me to  to convert color image bitmap to black & white image bitmap in android.

Answer (score 4):

This question is long ago, but probably I could help other users.
I also had a long search for creating (fast)a pure Black and White bitmap.

My first methode used bitmap.getPixel() and bitmap.setPixel()
This took about 8s (832 x 1532)
New Method took 0.4s! Thanks factor 20!

Now I load all Pixels in an int array and go so through all pixels with getPixels(..) and setPixels(..):
Here my method:

```
public static Bitmap createBlackAndWhite(Bitmap src) {
    int width = src.getWidth();
    int height = src.getHeight();

    Bitmap bmOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    final float factor = 255f;
    final float redBri = 0.2126f;
    final float greenBri = 0.2126f;
    final float blueBri = 0.0722f;

    int length = width * height;
    int[] inpixels = new int[length];
    int[] oupixels = new int[length];

    src.getPixels(inpixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);

    int point = 0;
    for(int pix: inpixels){
        int R = (pix >> 16) & 0xFF;
        int G = (pix >> 8) & 0xFF;
        int B = pix & 0xFF;

        float lum = (redBri * R / factor) + (greenBri * G / factor) + (blueBri * B / factor);

        if (lum > 0.4) {
            oupixels[point] = 0xFFFFFFFF;
        }else{
            oupixels[point] = 0xFF000000;
        }
        point++;
    }
    bmOut.setPixels(oupixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
    return bmOut;
}
```

Comment: Shall we increase contrast with same logic?

Answer (score 2):

You could convert the image applying a color filter in this way:

```
Bitmap bwBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bwBitmap );
//set contrast
ColorMatrix contrastMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
//change contrast
float contrast = 50.f;
float shift = (-.5f * contrast + .5f) * 255.f;
contrastMatrix .set(new float[] {
       contrast , 0, 0, 0, shift ,
       0, contrast , 0, 0, shift ,
       0, 0, contrast , 0, shift ,
       0, 0, 0, 1, 0 });
//apply contrast
Paint contrastPaint = new Paint();
contrastPaint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(contrastMatrix ));
canvas.drawBitmap(colorBitmap, 0, 0, contrastPaint);

//set saturation
ColorMatrix saturationMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
saturationMatrix.setSaturation(0); //you set color saturation to 0 for b/w
//apply new saturation
Paint saturationPaint = new Paint();
saturationPaint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(saturationPaint));
canvas.drawBitmap(colorBitmap, 0, 0, saturationPaint);
```

Comment: If i use above code it will produce gray-scale image, not pure black & white image, in my application need to read the text in the Business card/ visiting card. please help me.

Comment: usuallly a grey-scale image is considered as b/w. What you want is a grey-scale image with high constrast so that dark greys became black and light greys become white. You can achive that changing the image contrast. I edited my comment inserting the code to do that setting proprerly a ColorMatrix. Try to change contrast value to find the best result for you.

Comment: if i using above ma.set() method, again it will be changing grasy-scale image to colored image with contrast. please help me.

Comment: oh yes..sorry! I updated the code. The second colormatrix were replacing the first one. Applying two separate drawbitmap it should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ColorMatrix` and `ColorFilter`class in android to convert to Black and White.
Use this `ColorMatrix` - `ColorMatrix cm1 = new ColorMatrix(new float[]{0.5f,0.5f,0.5f,0,0, 
                    0.5f,0.5f,0.5f,0,0, 
                    0.5f,0.5f,0.5f,0,0, 
                    0,0,0,1,0,0, 
                    0,0,0,0,1,0 
                    });`